# Adding Box2d extension to Android Studio

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Downloaded Box2d from [here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension) but after going

```
Project Structure > New Module > Import existing library
```

When asking for path i put the box2d path and still get the warning that doesnt let me continue

> Select modules to import

What is the problem?

Comment: How have you imported andengine and box2d?

Comment: I use this method and works perfectly. http://javaprogrammernotes.blogspot.in/2014/05/settings-up-andengine-in-android-studio.html?m=1

Comment: got error after sync `Error:(14, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()`  on andengineBox2d. I check and the method is there!.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add PhysicsBox2D as Module, Download the JAR From this link :-http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgandengineextensionphysicsbox2djar.htm
and copy jar and paste in project library folder.

And then go to File->Project Structure-> app->dependencies-> + ->File Dependency -> lib ->add that jar file.

And if want to check that box2D is added or not try to import that:-
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d
in MainActivity.java. If importing Box2D is set in Project.

Comment: If someone wants to download AndEngine.jar and Box2d.jar separately from Github:
https://github.com/erincatto/box2d 
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine 
Because it seems java2s.com website may be not good website for downloads.